# sed - insert section from file before first match

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file named **extras** which contains below data:

```
<section10>
  <name>Yahoo</name>
</section10>
<section11>
  <name>Google</name>
</section11>
<section12>
  <name>Microsoft</name>
</section12>
<section13>
  <name>Facebook</name>
</section13>
<section14>
  <name>Yahoo</name>
</section14>
```

And a second file named **main-data.xml**, which has below data (it's a file with 5000+ lines). Below is an excerpt:

```
<section>
  <name>Yahoo</name>
</section>
<section>
  <name>Google</name>
</section2>
<section>
  <name>Microsoft</name>
</section>
<section>
  <name>Facebook</name>
</section>
<section>
  <name>Yahoo</name>
</section>
```

I want to insert whole data from **extras** file to **main-data.xml**, but before first occurrence of `<section>` or last occurrence of `</section>`. How can I do that?

Comment: oh....it is xml, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it a xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, using combination of grep - to find first occurrence of  and sed to put contents.